# ADB query for browser

Tags: android, adb

I am having some slight issue using the query

```
adb shell content query --uri content://browser/bookmarks" & "adb shell content query --uri content://browser/searches
```

and

```
adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.chrome/bookmarks"
```

I have played around with the browser and added some bookmarks, but I am receiving nothing in return. Does anyone have encounter any issue using the queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more digging through google, apparently the queries has been depreciated. So the alternative solution I could come out with would be. Hope it helps whoever needs in.

```
cat /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Bookmarks
```